# Get the proper href link using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am writing a web scraper and am struggling to get the href link from a web page. The URL is https://vcnewsdaily.com/tessera-therapeutics/venture-capital-funding/rsgclpxrcp. I am trying to get the href link below:

```
<div class="mb-2">
             <a href="https://vcnewsdaily.com/Tessera%20Therapeutics/venture-funding.php"> &gt;&gt; Click here for more funding data on Tessera Therapeutics</a>
             </div>
```

Here is my code:

```
from cgi import print_directory
import pandas as pd
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

URL = "https://vcnewsdaily.com/tessera-therapeutics/venture-capital-funding/rsgclpxrcp"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
links = []

for link in soup.findAll(class_='mb-2'):
    links.append(link.get('href'))
print(links)
```

When I run the code, it outputs:

```
[None, None, None, None]
```

Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `link` doesn't contain `<a>` tag with `href=` attribute. To select all `<a>` under tags with class `.mb-2` you can use for example CSS selector:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://vcnewsdaily.com/tessera-therapeutics/venture-capital-funding/rsgclpxrcp"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
links = []

for link in soup.select(".mb-2 a"):  # <-- select <a> tags here
    links.append(link.get("href"))
print(links)
```

Prints:

```py
['https://vcnewsdaily.com/Tessera%20Therapeutics/venture-funding.php', 'https://vcnewsdaily.com/marketing.php']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code almost works, just use `find` instead of `get` and search for `a`:

```
from cgi import print_directory
import pandas as pd
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

URL = "https://vcnewsdaily.com/tessera-therapeutics/venture-capital-funding/rsgclpxrcp"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
links = []

for link in soup.findAll(class_='mb-2'):
    links.append(link.find('a'))
print(links)
```